# How to detect if a column is increasing continuously in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table sorted by 'category' and 'number'. I'm trying to detect the rows that don't have an increasing number. I've tried this approach:

```
WITH test AS (
    SELECT * FROM (
        VALUES
            ('A', 1),
            ('B', 2),
            ('C', 4),
            ('D', 3),
            ('F', 5),
            ('F', 6),
            ('G', 7),
            ('H', 9),
            ('H', 8)
    ) AS t(category, number)
),
test_with_previous as(
select t.*, 
  lag(number) over (order by category, number) as prev_number
  from test t
)
select *
from test_with_previous
where prev_number > number;
```

Which gives:

| category | number | prev_number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| D | 3 | 4 |

But the first unordered row should be "C". How can I fix it?

Comment: Well, D is the first row where the number decreases. Are you looking for the first row that has a difference to the previous row different from one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `ROW_NUMBER()` to data to get sequence number and then `JOIN` with next record and filter all with increment not equal to 1, or you can simply adjust the filter to get whatever you want

```
;WITH 
test AS (
    SELECT * FROM (
        VALUES
            ('A', 1),
            ('B', 2),
            ('C', 4),
            ('D', 3),
            ('F', 5),
            ('F', 6),
            ('G', 7),
            ('H', 9),
            ('H', 8)
    ) AS t(category, number)
),
test_idx as (
    select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by category, number) id
    from test
)
select t1.id, t2.id, t1.category c1, t2.category c2, t1.number n1, t2.number n2, t2.number - t1.number diff
from test_idx t1
left join test_idx t2 on t1.id = t2.id-1
where t1.number <> t2.number -1;
```

Outputs

```
id  id  c1  c2  n1  n2  diff
2   3   B   C   2   4   2
3   4   C   D   4   3   -1
4   5   D   F   3   5   2
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `lead()` instead of `lag()`:

```
WITH test (category, number) AS (
  VALUES
   ('A', 1),
   ('B', 2),
   ('C', 4),
   ('D', 3),
   ('F', 5),
   ('F', 6),
   ('G', 7),
   ('H', 9),
   ('H', 8)), 
 test_with_next AS(
SELECT t.*, lead(number) OVER (ORDER BY category, number) AS next_number
FROM test t)
SELECT *
FROM test_with_next
WHERE next_number < number;

 category | number | next_number 
----------+--------+-------------
 C        |      4 |           3
```